# flask-migrate issue while refactoring code

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy, factory-pattern, flask-migrate

I got the below file structure for a Python-Flask app with flask-migrate :

[image: File Structure]

My issues are

1-I'm  unable to use db and create_app inside manage.py

When I do:

```
$ python manage.py db init
```

I got below error:

```
File "/app/main/model/model.py", line 25, in <module>
    class User(db.Model):
NameError: name 'db' is not defined
```

(db is defined in main.**init**.py )

I have tried different options with no success.

I want to keep the manage.py , model.py and main.**init**.py in separate files.

2- In model .py I will need db .How will I make db available to model.py ?

Here below is manage.py

```
# This file take care of the migrations
# in model.py we have our tables
import os
import unittest

from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask_script import Manager

from app.main import create_app
from app.main import db
# # We import the tables into the migrate tool
from app.main.model import model


app = create_app(os.getenv('BOILERPLATE_ENV') or 'dev')

app.app_context().push()

manager = Manager(app)

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

#### If I add  model.py here all should be easier , but still I have the 
#### issue with 
#### from app.main import create_app , db


@manager.command
def run():
    app.run()


@manager.command
def test():
    """Runs the unit tests."""
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('app/test', pattern='test*.py')
    result = unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(tests)
    if result.wasSuccessful():
        return 0
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

This is app.**init**.py where db and create_app are defined

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_cors import CORS

from .config import config_by_name

from flask_restful import Resource, Api
# from flask_restplus import Resource
from app.main.controller.api_controller import gconnect, \
     showLogin, createNewTest, getTest, getTests, getIssue, createNewIssue

db = SQLAlchemy()
flask_bcrypt = Bcrypt()


def create_app(config_name):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_by_name[config_name])
    cors = CORS(app,
                supports_credentials=True,
                resources={r"/api/*":
                           {"origins":
                            ["http://localhost:3000",
                             "http://127.0.0.1:3000"]}})
    api = Api(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    flask_bcrypt.init_app(app)

    api.add_resource(gconnect, '/api/gconnect')
    api.add_resource(showLogin, '/login')
    api.add_resource(createNewTest, '/api/test')
    api.add_resource(getTest, '/api/test/<int:test_id>')
    api.add_resource(getTests, '/api/tests')
    api.add_resource(getIssue, '/api/issue/<int:issue_id>')
    api.add_resource(createNewIssue, '/api/issue')

    return app
```

And this is (just one of the table for simplicity) of my model

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String, DateTime
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import func


# # # This will let sql alchemy know that these clasess
# # # are special Alchemy classes
# Base = declarative_base()



class User(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
    pictures = db.Column(db.String(250))
    role = db.Column(db.String(25), nullable=True)
```

My issues are:

1-I'm  unable to use db and create_app inside manage.py

When I do:

$ python manage.py db init

I got below error:

File "/app/main/model/model.py", line 25, in 
    class User(db.Model):
NameError: name 'db' is not defined

(db is defined in main.**init**.py )

I have tried different options with no success.

I want to keep the manage.py , model.py and main.**init**.py in separate files.

2- In model .py I will need db .How will I make db available to model.py ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to create a seperate initializtions file besides your `__init__.py`. e.g. `init.py` where you initialize sqlalchemy along with other extensions. That way they can be imported in all the modules without any circular dependencies problems.

A more elegant solution however is to you use Flask's `current_app` and `g` proxies. They were made to help Flask users circumvent any problems with circular dependencies.

Typically you initalize the flask `app` in the `__init__.py` module and the `__init__.py` module sometimes has to import some variables from its sub-modules. This becomes problematic when sub-modules try to import initalized extensions

As a general rule of thumb, outer modules should be importing from their submodules not the other way around.

So here's one way you can solve your problem (cited from [here](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/appcontext/#storing-data)):

** `__init__.py`

```
from flask import g

def get_db():
    if 'db' not in g:
        g.db = connect_to_database()

    return g.db

@app.teardown_appcontext
def teardown_db():
    db = g.pop('db', None)

    if db is not None:
        db.close()


def init_db():
    db = get_db()
```

Now you can easily import your db connection into any other module by:

```
from flask import g

db = g.db
db.do_something()
```

Comment: The root cause of this issue is the fact that I wanted to improve the code , by splitting some large files in multiple smaller files .However This lead to circular reference issues .I manage to solve some , but still could not solve all. Is my opinion that this case shows the importance of select the correct framework for your need and our limitations as developers

Comment: Well, Flask is a microframework, which means it lets you write apps with minimum amount files, making such problems evident. Have you tried using `g`?

Comment: You are right . g is one solution to this problem. I actually did something more simple.Just created  module where I declared the global variable that was causing the issue . Now I have a much cleaner code. Next step is using g .But I have to go step by step . Even though I did not use your recommendation your response is correct.Thanks for your help Charming Robot :-)